# When should I return by T const&?

Tags: c++

When should I return by `T const&`? If I am not going to modify the object, I do not see how it is any different from returning by value. And returning by const reference really just means no copy is made. So when is returning by `T const&` useful.

Comment: When you _don't want_ to make a copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two reasons why you would prefer to return by `const&` rather than by value.

The first is semantics.  A code which returns something by `const&` is telling the caller *explicitly*, "here is a read-only version of what you asked for.  If you want to store it permanently, or make changes to it, you are responsible for making a copy of it."  The semantics of this return type are quite clear, and easily enforced.

The second is optimization.  By returning something by-value, you remove some optimization opportunities from the compiler.  That is *not* to say that returning by-value **is** less efficient than returning by `const&` (in fact, in cases the opposite *might* be true -- consider a function that returns a `char` on a 64-bit system).  It simply means you remove one of the tools from the compiler's optimization toolbox.  There is another tool there to replace it -- namely, inlining the call along with copy elision -- so this might be a wash.  It all depends on context.

I mention "semantics" as the first reason because I consider it to be the most important.  There are so many variables with optimization and so many moving parts that it's often hard to know just what optimizations the compiler will be able to employ and when.  One thing is certian all the time however -- clear semantics are more easily understood by humans than muddled semantics.

Comment: I don't get the first bullet. How just & implicitly informs on how long do I have to make the copy?

Comment: The `const` is important.  You cannot change something returned by `const&`.

Comment: Also, you do not *necesarrily* have to make a copy.  You could store a `const&` as with `const Foo& returnedFoo = GetFoo()`, but since that is also `const`, you can't change that either.  The fact that it is a reference also implies (not universally true) that `returnedFoo` is only valid as long as the object `GetFoo()` belongs to is alive.

Comment: I thought we're in the context comparing return by-value vs const& not & vs. const&.

Comment: I'm as baffled on your second paragraph as I was asking the first question. For example the std:: collections go length to describe semantics of functions involved with pointers, references, and those differ from type to type. And you seem to claim it's something implicitly deducible just from signature.

Comment: @BalogPal:  Not just signature, but also idiom.  Are you hung up on "store it permanently?"

Answer (score 2):

A common case where you'd return `const T&` is a `const` getter member function:

```
T& get() { return m_some_private_member; }

const T& get() const { return m_some_private_member; }
```

In this case you often don't want to make a copy - you just want to return a reference to some object, and for the sake of const-correctness you may also need to provide a `const` getter.

Comment: Note: I would note that the `T& get();` method is an anti-pattern as by giving away a write-access to a class attribute you implicitly forgo any class invariant related to this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sufficiently stable object.

One trivial case is for a collection that returns the content that way. Kinda the primary job description.

For nonconst & another usual case is to return what you got in arguments (including the hidden this pointer). That could apply to const& in a similar way, but be aware of risks, when your param was bound to a temporary that will disappear in short time.   Would work better if you got & and return const& after changing the content.

You can return reference to a data member, but it fits the "do not leak your guts" guideline.

In any case if you return ref, you must provide documentation to the client on the validity. If you start working out that description, you will discover whether it makes sense in the first place.

Another obvious case is identity objects, that can (or supposed) not to be copied. It make sense to have to accessors, one returning const& for mainstream use and another with write access.

Answer (score 0):

For the very reason you specified: *no copy is made*.

If you're returning a large object, it is much more efficient to return a const reference than a copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Not making a copy is more efficient, especially for complex types, or types that do a lot of work in their copy constructor.

Comment: Can be more efficient, it depends on the semantics surrounding the logic.  See:  http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: huh.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

So you can avoid you function being misused as the one below does?

```
class A
{
int x;

public:

int show()
{
return x;
}

A(int a)
{
        x = a;
}

A const& operator+(A& inp)
{

inp.x = this->x + inp.x;

return inp;
}

};

int main()
{
A a(1),b(2),c(0),d(420);
a + b = d;
std::cout<<b.show();

}
```

This gives, `420` as output. The overload is supposed to be used as `d = a + b`, but there is nothing stopping the returned reference to be assigned a another object.

If you make the return type of the function as `A const&` The returned reference is constant and cant be assigned any other object. Hence the operator has to be used **only** as `d = a + b` and not allowing `a + b = d` etc.

g++ gives error `error: passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’ discards qualifiers` and effectively prevents such misuse.

Comment: this sounds like answer to an opposite question