# What does 'const' signify in function declaration 'int const& foo()'?

Tags: c++, constants, function-declaration

What does `const` signify in a function declaration like `int const& foo()`? Does it mean the function will not modify any variables, or that it returns the address of a variable which is constant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I return by T const&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964107/when-should-i-return-by-t-const)

Comment: It's the same thing as const int & foo();

Answer (score 1):

It's the latter case in your question. `int const& foo()` means that the function returns a reference to a `const int`. So, you can't do something like  `foo() = 42`, for instance.